# Is there any possible way to get image "src" from find_elements_by_class it just all returning None

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I get 250 Total results.
I tried to get 10 of the first result's image src but all return None.
If i switch to use XPATH it can't be done automatically because there are too many of them to be manually selected.

```
historylist = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "coinflip-list__item.coinflip-history-list__item")))
print(f"Total {len(historylist)}")
for x in range(10):
    print(historylist[x].get_attribute("src"))
```

Total 250
Printing out first 10:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="7bb1f785-409c-42c8-a85e-b6a7abd9d7be")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="4c445a89-003a-4e42-95b5-4dd0648d3a99")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="a0d21128-055d-4320-aae1-f1bebb532c2d")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="7606d8a6-332b-4584-932f-da0a8203918b")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="619896b8-b79d-4dba-b130-869a758402f7")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="d20d2480-b7e8-49e3-a66d-127c021d133e")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="4a60889a-58a4-4a77-a033-9303b001fbfa")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="0514a847-0571-4415-b6e6-d9cb96294525")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="8b150b8f-31ec-4090-b983-6a5992f97e41")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="7f909f2d-3459-47ba-9520-04979d958ddd")>

That's the output.

Comment: Are you sure "historylist" contains 250 web elements here and all of them, at least the first 10 are containing "src" attribute?

Comment: they all contain "src" i heard some people say you can't extract "src" from find_element_by_class since they are div not img

Comment: No, I'm asking about debugging your code results. After running the `historylist = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "coinflip-list__item.coinflip-history-list__item")))` line what is the content of `historylist` list?

Comment: hold up a few minutes

Comment: I'm quite sure `historylist` will be an empty list here. If it is correct I will explain you why :)

Comment: since it 250 collected result im just gonna print out 10 first one for short

Comment: This I understand. But I guess `historylist` is not actually getting what you think. That's why I'm asking you to debug and tell me the ACTUAL content of it in a run time

Comment: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d6ac99726310ff2fc4b6070ea0ab7fec", element="7f909f2d-3459-47ba-9520-04979d958ddd")>
i can't comment longer so imma post 1

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: how tho @itronic1990

Comment: can you paste the html here in the comments section or can you share the url?

Comment: it kinda an illegal website so idrk

Comment: it contain gamble

Comment: @itronic1990 please don't ask for code to be shared in comments, it should be in the question itself. Also, we should not ask for [links to offsite urls](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408059/problematic-number-of-questions-in-the-selenium-tag-that-rely-on-offsite-links?cb=1)

Comment: @porudev You have `print(f"Total {len(historylist)}")` Which I assume prints "Total 250"? Then, where is "Printing out first 10:" coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your use of `By.CLASS_NAME` is incorrect.
Here

```
historylist = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "coinflip-list__item.coinflip-history-list__item")))
```

`CLASS_NAME` or `find_element_by_class_name` or `find_elements_by_class_name` accepts only a single class. Compound classes are not working.

Change it to `By.CSS_SELECTOR`:

```
historylist = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".coinflip-list__item.coinflip-history-list__item")))
```

Where `coinflip-list__item` and `coinflip-history-list__item` are class names in a single html tag.

Check here for description: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name.

**Second**, try using `visibility_of_all_elements_located` instead of `presence_of_all_elements_located`.

Other than that, check that your locator is correct.